# Subprocess returning No such file or directory for file that exists

Tags: python, file, subprocess, tornado

I have a snippet of code that is attempting to submit an audio file for transcription to the bing speech api using SpeechRecognition (available in PyPi):

```
filename = 'part' + str(entry['srcID']) + '.flac'
with open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
    harkclient.getSeparatedAudio(handle=filehandle, srcID=entry['srcID'])
with speech_recognition.AudioFile(path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), filename)) as source:
    audio = speechclient.record(source)
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
File "./websocket_server.py", line 105, in send_data
    with speech_recognition.AudioFile(path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), filename)) as source:
  File "/srv/www/harkvisualizer/harkenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 195, in __enter__
    ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file exists

```
(harkenv) root@ip-172-31-28-12:/srv/www/harkvisualizer# ls | grep flac
part0.flac
```

I printed the path being passed to the AudioFile() function, which was correct. I also played the audio file just to be sure it was what I expected. I tried adding shell=True arg in the source code for the popen call since I read about some potential issues with that, but it did not resolve. This is running in a virtual environment, within a websocket code block that sends data to a browser (I'm converting the text and sending it to a webpage). I'm not sure if that could be an issue.

System information:

Python version for venv and system:

```
(harkenv) root@ip-172-31-28-12:/srv/www/harkvisualizer# which python
/srv/www/harkvisualizer/harkenv/bin/python

(harkenv) root@ip-172-31-28-12:/srv/www/harkvisualizer# python --version
Python 2.7.6

root@ip-172-31-28-12:/srv/www/harkvisualizer# /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

My **SpeechRecognition library version** is 3.4.6.

Comment: Triple quotes aren't recognized here; use four-space indents for code formatting, or select the relevant section and use the `{}` button.

Comment: That said, where are you generating the input file name with `.flac` (as opposed to `.wav`) on the end? As I read the code, it would be trying to read `part0.wav`, the existence of which you aren't demonstrating. Printing the actual value for `path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), filename)` would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, `shell=True` generally creates more bugs than it solves, some of them obscure (and present only when dealing with unusual filenames or argument values); adding it as a hail-Mary [without understanding the behavioral changes involved] is ill-advised.

Comment: Hi Charles. I did print the path just before that line. It was /srv/www/harkvisualizer/part0.flac. I've been alternating between trying this with a .flac file and trying it with a .wav file, but had issues with both. Apologies, my search for the file was from when I was testing with .flac. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Which user is the web server running as? If you use `sudo -u <username> -i` to become that user, can you then `cd` to the relevant directory and access the file in question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In that case the error would be about permissions not a missing file.

Comment: All of this is in a python script which I am running as root. I first sudo su, then activate the virtual env, then run the script via python web-socket.py (I've also tried ./web-socket.py) which starts the web socket listener and http server from the script. The error is coming from the module that's taking this audio file and sending it to Bing speech API by spawning a subprocess for some task. An ls on the files as root user shows permissions are -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    36K Jun 27 21:39 part0.flac.

Comment: To clarify, they are spawning a subprocess to read the file: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer for this one as per the full code snippet:

[https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/**init**.py#L195](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L195)

the flac encoder/decoder is missing from your box:

```
sudo apt-get install flac
```